# Using LIKE on 2 columns from 2 tables with join on a 3rd table

Tags: postgresql, join

I'd like some help with using `LIKE` and `join`s on tables. Im currently a student and taking a class where the emphasis has been on relational algebra so far. Based on that, my intuition would be to do multiple cartesian products and then set conditions and project what I want. However, I'm not quite understanding SQL. What I am attempting to do with the query below is primarily get an approximate match of the account name vs the drawer name from a bunch of specific documents(Invoices). If an invoice is found for that account, use its id to return the internal id on that account from AccountsMonitoredBy and the details on that document.

Here's the logic I suppose:

> if Accounts.accname in Documents.drawer: 
>   then if Accounts.accountid =
>   AccountsMonitoredBy.accid
>         return AccountsMonitoredBy.internal_id, Documents.docnum, Documents.doc_date, Accounts.accname

```
SELECT "AccountsMonitoredBy".internal_id, "Accounts".accname, "Documents".docnum, "Documents".doc_date
    FROM "Accounts", "Documents", "AccountsMonitoredBy"
    WHERE "Accounts".accname LIKE '%'  || "Documents".drawer || '%' and "Documents".doc_type = 'INVOICE' 
    and "AccountsMonitoredBy".accid = "Accounts".accountid
```

Please, help with an explanation as to how it's achieved and not just a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not meant to be a place to get help on homework.

Comment: It’s not homework.  There’s always chegg for that. I mentioned it to show the extent or level of my understanding. However this is for a production level database that I work on as a professional.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of input data and the output you want the query to produce?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it would do something like what you describe, so it should be a correct solution, but there are some things that could be improved:

1. You don't use SQL join syntax. To avoid the common mistake to forget a join condition (a projection), write:

   ```
   SELECT "AccountsMonitoredBy".internal_id,
          "Accounts".accname,
          "Documents".docnum,
          "Documents".doc_date
   FROM "Accounts"
      JOIN "Documents"
         ON "Accounts".accname LIKE '%' || "Documents".drawer || '%'
      JOIN "AccountsMonitoredBy"
         ON "AccountsMonitoredBy".accid = "Accounts".accountid
   WHERE "Documents".doc_type = 'INVOICE';
   ```
2. Don't use upper case letters in object names so that you don't have to quote the identifiers.
3. The join condition between `"Accounts"` and `"Documents"` will make the query very inefficient.

   Not only is the only join strategy for such a condition a nested loop join, but the way it is written, it cannot use a B-tree index and will lead to a sequential scan (a *trigram index* might help somewhat).

Comment: Thank you for the help with syntax, it really makes it easier to see what I am trying to achieve. Regarding efficiency, we don't have anyway to link id's of documents to their drawers and accounts and therefore have to make do with inefficient name matching ☹️.